# Как работает экспорт классов? Классы ES6 и Node.js module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ооп, ecmascript-6

Я экспортирую класс через module.exports

```
// class.js
const int = 123
class ClassName {
  constructor(param) {
    this.param = param
  }
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log(this.param)
  }
  publicMethod() {
    ClassName.staticMethod()
  }
}
module.exports = new ClassName(int)
```

В приложении импортирую модуль:

```
// app.js
const importClass = require('./class');
importClass.publicMethod()
```

В `console.log` получаю `undefined`

Почему параметр не передаётся в класс?

Comment: При чем тут экспорт классов - если у вас и в одном модуле не будет работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вызове конструктора: `this` - это новый создаваемый объект.

Поэтому присваивая

```
this.param = param
```

В *новый* объект добавляется поле *param*.

Статический метод относится к *классу* и `this` внутри него - это *класс*.

А так как у `ClassName` нет поля *param* - в выводе ожидаемый *undefined*.